# sort an array with first three characters of array values

Tags: php, sorting, utf-8

I have an array that contains some UTF-8 characters from different languages. Every entry in the array is prepended by an alphanumeric value with a space in between. I want to sort my array by this alphanumeric value instead of the whole array value. How can I do this? My array is as follows.

```
$array[0]="1. Mme Costa parle un peu français"
$array[1]="2b. C’est en France ou au Canada ?"
$array[2]="1a. C’est en France ou au Canada ?"
$array[3]="2a. Comment ça va ?"
```

secondly is there a php function that sorts this array so that i dont have to sort it by the prepended values inorder to place them in the right order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the uksort function is the one youre searching for?

edit: by the way, you could just explode your string, if that's necessary.